# How to fetch image in database using while in php

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I'm trying to fetch the image from my database using while loop in php but there's an error. can anyone help me? sorry for my bad english.

```
<div class="gallery" id="links">

                <?php
                     $query = $dbconn->query("select * from `uploading`") or die(mysqli_error());
                     while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()){
                                       ?>

                    <a class="gallery-item" href="artifactimage/<?php echo $fetch['artifact_image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>" data-gallery>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="artifactimage/<?php echo $fetch['artifact_image']; ?>" width="400" height="150" alt="<?php echo $fetch['artifact_name']; ?>" />
                            <ul class="gallery-item-controls">
                                <li><label class="check"><input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox" /></label></li>
                                <li><span class="gallery-item-remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <strong>
                                <?php echo $fetch['artifact_name']; ?></strong>
                            <span>
                                <?php echo $fetch['artifact_desc']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <div id="preview"><img src="filed.png" /></div><br>

                <?php
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

The error:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: title in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\HAHMIS\artifactlist.php** on line **9**

Comment: "there's an error"  What is the exact error?

Comment: can you post the database schema of the table ?

Comment: this is the error
"<br ></a> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: title in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\HAHMIS\artifactlist.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />"

I used ajax in this but it works. the only problem is that the image is not showing it only shows the alt text

 <img src="artifactimage/<?php echo $fetch['artifact_image']; ?>" width="400" height="150" alt="<?php echo $fetch['artifact_name']; ?>" />

Comment: You are trying to use the variable `$title`, but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: should it not be `$fetch['artifact_title']` rather than simply`$title`? Pure guess btw

Comment: Sorry for my question guys. I just got solve the problem a minute ago. thanks for your help anyways

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)